# R shiny reactive value does not recalculate when called from DT::renderDT

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, dt

A reactive value in my shiny app does not recalculate when it is being called from inside DT::renderDT function after the 1st calculation.

Here is my code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT & PACKAGES
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set working directory
setwd('C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding projects/Paleo Diet Planner')

# Clear workspace
rm(list = ls())

# Package/library list
pckgs <- c('shiny','shinydashboard','reactlog','DT','dplyr','stringr','mgsub')

# Install and load libraries
for(pckg in pckgs)
{
  if(!(pckg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) install.packages(pckg)
  if(!(pckg %in% (.packages()))) library(pckg, character.only = TRUE)
}

# Remove unnecessary variables
rm(pckg,pckgs)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATA
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Static Data
Recipe_Inv <- readRDS('./Data/Recipe_Inv.rds')

# Get unique tags
Recipe_Tags <- Recipe_Inv$Tags %>% stringr::str_split(., ';', simplify = T) %>%
  trimws %>% as.vector %>% unique %>% magrittr::extract(. != '') %>% magrittr::extract(order(.))

# Utility variables
Debug_Flag <- F
Log_Flag <- T
LogFile <- c()
LogFile_Path <- as.character(Sys.time()) %>% mgsub(., c('-', ' ', ':'), c('', '_', '-')) %>% paste0('./Logs/',.,'.txt')

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTILITY FUNCTIONS
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Function for checking if the tags chosen for filtering are present in the tag string, i.e.
# string with tags separated by semi-colon
Filter_Tags <- function(Tags, Tag_Crit){
  # Debug and log
  # if(Log_Flag) print('Utility_Function -> Filter_Tags')
  if(Debug_Flag) browser()
  
  #Extract tags from the tag string as character vector
  Tag_Ls <- trimws(stringr::str_split(Tags, ';')[[1]])
  
  # Check if the intersection (common elements) of the tag string and filter tags vector have the same length
  # Equivalent to all filter tags being present in the tag string
  length(intersect(Tag_Ls, Tag_Crit)) == length(Tag_Crit)
}

# Function to filter out, rearrange and order the tags when select drop-down field is used
ReArrange_Tags <- function(Tags, Tag_Crit){
  # Log
  # if(Log_Flag) print('Utility_Function - > ReArrange_Tags')
  
  if(is.null(Tag_Crit)){
    # If the select drop-down list is empty, leave tag string (tags delimited by semi-colon) as-is
    Tags
  }else{
    # Debug
    if(Debug_Flag) browser()
    
    # Get the tags in the tag string that were chosen in the select drop-down field
    # and order them aplhabetically
    trimws(stringr::str_split(Tags, ';')[[1]]) %>% 
      intersect(., Tag_Crit) %>% magrittr::extract(order(.)) %>%
      paste0(., collapse = ';')
  }
}

# Function for logging events in the apps in terms of UI element usage and server activity
Log_App_Activity <- function(print_txt){
  print(print_txt)
  LogFile <<- c(LogFile,print_txt)
  write.table(LogFile, LogFile_Path, sep = '\n', col.names = F, row.names = F)
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# USER INTERFACE
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#### Separate components #### 

# Dashboard Header
db_header <- shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
  # Dashboard title
  title = 'Paleo Diet Planner'
)

# Dashboard Sidebar
db_Sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
  #### Sidebar settings ####
  # ID of the dashboard sidebar object
  id = 'InSidebar_Menu',
  
  # Width setting
  width = 350,
  
  #### UI elements ####
  #
  shiny::selectInput(inputId = 'InSelect_RecipeTags',
                     label = 'Select Recipe Categories',
                     choices = Recipe_Tags, multiple = T),
  
  #
  shinydashboard::menuItem(text = 'Recipe List', tabName = 'tbRecipeLs',
                           icon = shiny::icon('th-list')),
  
  #
  shinydashboard::menuItem(text = 'Recipe View', tabName = 'tbRecipeView',
                           icon = shiny::icon('readme'))
)

# Dashboard Body
db_Body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
  
  #
  shinydashboard::tabItems(
    #
    shinydashboard::tabItem(
      #
      tabName = 'tbRecipeLs',
      #
      DT::DTOutput(outputId = 'OutDT_RecipeList')
    ),
    
    #
    shinydashboard::tabItem(
      #
      tabName = 'tbRecipeView',
      #
      shiny::uiOutput('OutUI_RecipeURL'),
      #
      shiny::htmlOutput("OutUI_RecipeWebsite")
    )
  )
)

#### Main UI #### 
Main_UI <- dashboardPage(db_header, db_Sidebar, db_Body)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SERVER
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Filtered Recipe Inventory based on the select drop-down field 'InSelect_RecipeTags'
  Recipe_Inv_Flt <- shiny::reactive({
    # Debug and log
    if(Log_Flag) Log_App_Activity('shiny::reactive -> Recipe_Inv_Flt')
    if(Debug_Flag) browser()
    
    # Check if the select drop-down field 'InSelect_RecipeTags' has been used and filter appropriately
    if(is.null(input$InSelect_Recipe_Tags)){
      Recipe_Inv
    }else{
      Recipe_Inv %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>%
        dplyr::filter(Filter_Tags(Tags, input$InSelect_RecipeTags)) %>%
        dplyr::ungroup()
    }
  })
  
  # Data Table displaying the reactive values Recipe_Inv_Flt() with appropriate tags displayed
  # in the tag column, based on the tags selected in the select drop-down field 'InSelect_RecipeTags'
  output$OutDT_RecipeList <- DT::renderDT({
    # Debug and log
    if(Log_Flag) Log_App_Activity('DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList')
    if(Debug_Flag) browser()
    
    # 
    Recipe_Inv_Flt() %>% dplyr::select(Tags, Recipe_Nm) %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>%
      dplyr::mutate(Tags = ReArrange_Tags(Tags, input$InSelect_RecipeTags)) %>%
      dplyr::ungroup() %>% dplyr::arrange(Tags)
  })
  
  #
  output$OutUI_RecipeURL <- shiny::renderUI({
    # Debug and log
    if(Log_Flag) Log_App_Activity('shiny::renderUI -> OutUI_RecipeURL')
    if(Debug_Flag) browser(text = 'shiny::renderUI -> OutUI_RecipeURL')
    
    #
    choices <- Recipe_Inv_Flt() %>% .$Recipe_Nm %>% magrittr::extract(input$OutDT_RecipeList_rows_selected)
    
    #
    shiny::selectInput(inputId = 'InSelect_RecipeURL',
                       label = 'Select recipe to display',
                       choices = choices, multiple = F)
  })
  
  #
  output$OutUI_RecipeWebsite <- shiny::renderUI({
    #Debug and log
    if(Log_Flag) Log_App_Activity('shiny::renderUI -> OutUI_RecipeWebsite')
    if(Debug_Flag) browser(text = 'shiny::renderUI -> OutUI_RecipeWebsite')
    
    #
    if(!is.null(input$InSelect_RecipeURL)){
      Recipe_URL <- Recipe_Inv %>% dplyr::filter(Recipe_Nm == input$InSelect_RecipeURL) %>% .$Recipe_URL
    }else{
      Recipe_URL <- NA
    }
    
    #
    shiny::tags$iframe(src = Recipe_URL, width = "100%", height = 800)
  })
  
  # Log for UI elements
  shiny::observeEvent(input$InSelect_RecipeTags,{
    browser()
    if(Log_Flag) Log_App_Activity('shiny::selectInput -> InSelect_RecipeTags')
  })
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$InSidebar_Menu,{
    browser()
    if(Log_Flag){
      switch(input$InSidebar_Menu,
             'tbRecipeLs' = Log_App_Activity('shinydashboard::menuIte -> tbRecipeLs'),
             'tbRecipeView' = Log_App_Activity('shinydashboard::menuIte -> tbRecipeView'))
    }
  })
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$InSelect_RecipeURL,{
    browser()
    if(Log_Flag) Log_App_Activity('shiny::selectInput -> InSelect_RecipeURL')
  })
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RUN APPLICATION
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

shiny::shinyApp(ui = Main_UI, server = server)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mgsub_1.7.3          stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_1.0.2          DT_0.14              reactlog_1.1.0       shinydashboard_0.7.1
[7] shiny_1.4.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_1.5      tidyselect_1.1.0  xtable_1.8-4      R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.11      fastmap_1.0.1    
 [9] tools_3.6.2       ellipsis_0.3.2    crosstalk_1.1.0.1 htmltools_0.4.0   yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.25     tibble_2.1.3      lifecycle_1.0.0  
[17] crayon_1.3.4      purrr_0.3.3       later_1.0.0       htmlwidgets_1.5.1 vctrs_0.3.4       promises_1.1.0    glue_1.4.1        mime_0.9         
[25] stringi_1.4.6     compiler_3.6.2    pillar_1.4.3      generics_0.0.2    jsonlite_1.7.0    httpuv_1.5.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

The `Recipe_Inv` variable has the following (20 sample rows) structure:

| Recipe_Nm | Recipe_URL | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Butter | https://paleoleap.com/apple-butter/ | PALEO DESSERTS;SWEETS AND SNACKS;COOKING: FAST PREP;COOKING: SLOW-COOKER;PALEO AUTOIMMUNE-FRIENDLY RECIPES;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;DIET: VEGETARIAN;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Baked Eggs With Asparagus and Leeks | https://paleoleap.com/baked-eggs-asparagus-leeks/ | PALEO PORK RECIPES;PALEO EGG RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO BREAKFAST RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: NUT-FREE;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Beef Pho | https://paleoleap.com/beef-pho/ | PALEO BEEF AND RED MEAT RECIPES;PALEO SOUP RECIPES;PALEO BREAKFAST RECIPES;PALEO LUNCH RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;PALEO AUTOIMMUNE-FRIENDLY RECIPES;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: LOW-FODMAP;DIET: NUT-FREE |
| Chicken Cashew Casserole | https://paleoleap.com/chicken-cashew-casserole/ | PALEO CHICKEN AND POULTRY RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE |
| Chicken With Garlic-Roasted Sweet Potatoes | https://paleoleap.com/chicken-garlic-roasted-sweet-potatoes/ | PALEO CHICKEN AND POULTRY RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Crab-Stuffed Deviled Eggs With Tarragon | https://paleoleap.com/crab-stuffed-deviled-eggs-tarragon/ | PALEO FISH AND SEAFOOD RECIPES;PALEO EGG RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: LOW-FODMAP;DIET: NUT-FREE;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS |
| Elk Shepherd’s Pie | https://paleoleap.com/elk-shepherd-pie/ | PALEO BEEF AND RED MEAT RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Fresh Fruit And Kale Salad | https://paleoleap.com/fresh-fruit-and-kale-salad/ | PALEO SALAD RECIPES;PALEO BREAKFAST RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: VEGETARIAN |
| Garlic-Roasted Cherry Tomatoes | https://paleoleap.com/garlic-roasted-cherry-tomatoes/ | PALEO SIDES;VEGGIES AND APPETIZERS;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;DIET: VEGETARIAN;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Ginger Carrot Soup | https://paleoleap.com/ginger-carrot-soup/ | PALEO SOUP RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO BREAKFAST RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;PALEO AUTOIMMUNE-FRIENDLY RECIPES;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;DIET: VEGETARIAN;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS |
| Grilled Pineapple Chicken | https://paleoleap.com/grilled-pineapple-chicken/ | PALEO CHICKEN AND POULTRY RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;COOKING: GRILL;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Italian-Style Fish Bowls | https://paleoleap.com/italian-style-fish-bowl/ | PALEO FISH AND SEAFOOD RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE |
| Keto Slow Cooker Chicken Soup | https://paleoleap.com/slow-cooker-chicken-soup/ | PALEO CHICKEN AND POULTRY RECIPES;PALEO SOUP RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;COOKING: SLOW-COOKER;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Maple-Barbecue Ribs | https://paleoleap.com/maple-barbecue-ribs/ | PALEO PORK RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Paleo Garlic Shrimp With Zucchini Noodles | https://paleoleap.com/garlic-shrimp-with-zucchini-noodle/ | PALEO FISH AND SEAFOOD RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO LUNCH RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;PALEO AUTOIMMUNE-FRIENDLY RECIPES;DIET: EGG-FREE;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Pumpkin Cookies | https://paleoleap.com/pumpkin-cookies/ | PALEO DESSERTS;SWEETS AND SNACKS;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: VEGETARIAN;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Sautéed Chicken And Cabbage | https://paleoleap.com/sauteed-chicken-cabbage/ | PALEO CHICKEN AND POULTRY RECIPES;PALEO LOW-CARB RECIPES;PALEO LUNCH RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Slow Cooker Butterkin And Nuts | https://paleoleap.com/slow-cooker-butterkin-and-nuts/ | PALEO SIDES;VEGGIES AND APPETIZERS;COOKING: FAST PREP;COOKING: SLOW-COOKER;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: VEGETARIAN;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |
| Slow Cooker Curry Chicken | https://paleoleap.com/slow-cooker-curry-chicken/ | PALEO CHICKEN AND POULTRY RECIPES;PALEO DINNER RECIPES;COOKING: SLOW-COOKER;DIET: EGG-FREE;DIET: NUT-FREE;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS |
| Special Sweet Potato Salad | https://paleoleap.com/special-sweet-potato-salad/ | PALEO SALAD RECIPES;COOKING: FAST COOK;COOKING: FAST PREP;DIET: NUT-FREE;PALEO BUDGET-FRIENDLY RECIPES;GOOD FOR LEFTOVERS;PALEO KID-FRIENDLY RECIPES |

When I start my app in RStudio, My starting screen looks like this:[image: Issue1_1]

After I click on `menuItem -> tbRecipeLs` on the Sidebar, the `DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList` function call is triggered which in turns triggers the `reactive -> Recipe_Inv_Flt()` variable, as shown by the output console generated by the `Log_App_Activity` UDF:

```
[1] "DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList"
[1] "shiny::reactive -> Recipe_Inv_Flt"
```

This displays the UI output `DT::DTOutput -> OutDT_RecipeList` in the dashboard main body:
[image: Issue1_2]

I try to filter out the recipes in the list by choosing a tag filter in the drop-down `selectInput -> InSelect_RecipeTags`, see below:
[image: Issue1_3]

and the following UI and server components are triggered, based on the `Log_App_Activity` UDF console output:

```
[1] "shiny::selectInput -> InSelect_RecipeTags"
[1] "DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList"
```

My expectation is that because the `DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList` is being called, `reactive -> Recipe_Inv_Flt()` variable should also be called again because it is inside the `DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList` function, as well as because its dependency, the drop-down field `selectInput -> InSelect_RecipeTags` is changed. However, this does not seem to be the case, based on the fact that the data table UI output `DT::DTOutput -> OutDT_RecipeList` still shows all the rows (1,555) however it does remove the tags from the ***Tags*** column, based on the filter values chosen in the drop-down field `selectInput -> InSelect_RecipeTags`, which is done by the `ReArrange_Tags` UDF call inside the `DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList` function. What should I do to make the `reactive -> Recipe_Inv_Flt()` variable recalculate every time it is being called from inside the `DT::renderDT -> OutDT_RecipeList` function?

Comment: You have a typo. You have `if(is.null(input$InSelect_Recipe_Tags))` but it should be `if(is.null(input$InSelect_RecipeTags))` (without the extra underscore).

Comment: @MrFlick, that's it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @MrFlick 's comment, the typo was the problem:
In the definition of `reactive -> Recipe_Inv_Flt()` the following `if` statement condition:

```
if(is.null(input$InSelect_Recipe_Tags))
```

should be (without the last underscore):

```
if(is.null(input$InSelect_RecipeTags))
```

Issue solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also I noticed that the `shinydashboard::menuItem` UI elements were not wrapped inside `shinydashboard::sidebarMenu` which was causing some undesirable behavior of the app, as well as the fact that the `id` attribute was showing in the sidebar (it's because `shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar` UI element does not have an `id` attribute, this attribute belongs to `shinydashboard::sidebarMenu`).